# Give the characteristics of a function after a relationship

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous, bounded function such that the space $\operatorname{lin}(\{f_k\mid k \in \mathbb{N}\})$ is finite-dimensional, where $f_k(x)=f(x+k)$.

What can we say about $f$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what can *you* say about $f$? Any thoughts, examples, ideas?

Comment: i do not understand the target of the exercise.

Comment: Pick a bounded, continuous function $f$. Look at all the functions $\dots,f(x-2),f(x-1),f(x),f(x+1),f(x+2),\dots$. They generate a vector space. Depending on the $f$ you picked, this vector space might be finite-dimensional, or it might be infinite-dimensional. You are being asked, suppose it's finite-dimensional; what does that tell you about $f$? As a warm-up exercise, you might try to prove that the functions $\sin x,\sin(x+1),\sin(x+2)$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: This tells me that f is generated by a finite number of vectors, For your exercise i can use $\forall r,x \in \mathbb{R} f_r(x)=sin(x+r)=sin(x)cos(r)+sin(r)cos(x)$ . So perhaps some $f_k$ are linearly dependent, but how can i prove that ? what's the point?

Comment: Huh? $f$ is a single vector. It isn't a vector space, so it makes no sense to speak of it being generated. In the exercise, you can prove that any three of the $f_k$ are linearly dependent, so the vector space generated by all the $f_k$ has dimension 2. So, $f(x)=\sin x$ gives an example where the space is finite-dimensional. So the question is, what distinguishes the functions $f$ where the space is finite-dimensional from the ones where it's infinite-dimensional. So do you now understand the "target" of the exercise?

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The question was just now undeleted, in case you're interested in giving an answer.

Comment: @T.Bongers, thanks for the heads-up. I think a good answer was posted to another posting of this question. Ah, found it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627515/study-of-subspace-generated-by-f-kx-fxk-with-f-continuous-bounded  At this point, it might be best to close the undeleted question as a duplicate.